# What is simplest way to find repeat unit of array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

for example,repeat unit of

```
1,1,1,1,1
```

is 1,

repeat unit of

```
1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2
```

is 1,3,2

repeat unit of

```
1,3,2,1,3,9,1,3,2
```

is 1,3,2,1,3,9,1,3,2

I try the idea like this:

1.try number of repeat unit test from 1,until the size of array

2.only try number which is multiple of the size of array,e.g.: n

3.check if n is the size of repeat unit,e.g.: assume testing repeat unit is 3, then check if

```
a[0]==a[3*1],a[1]==a[1+3*1],a[2]==a[2+3*1]
a[0]==a[3*2],a[1]==a[1+3*2],a[2]==a[2+3*2]
a[0]==a[3*r],a[1]==a[1+3*r],a[2]==a[2+3*r]
```

4. if the current testing number is repeat unit, break, and the current value of i is the size of repeat unit

I try to convert it to code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a[]={1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2};
    int i;
    //1.try number of repeat unit test from 1,until the size of array
    for(i=1;i<=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);i++){
        //2.only try number which is multiple of the size of array,e.g.: n
        int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
        if(n%i==0){
            //3.check if n is the size of repeat unit
            bool isRepeat=true;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                for(int r=1;r<i;r++){
                    if(a[j]!=a[j+r*n]){
                        isRepeat=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //4.if the current testing number is repeat unit, break, and the current value of i is the size of repeat unit
            if(isRepeat){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //print the result using repeat unit n
    for(int n=0;n<i;n++){
        printf("%d ",a[n]);
    }
};
```

but it shows the repeat unit of 1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2 is 1 instead of 1,3,2. And I think this solving idea is too complex as it has too many for loops. Is there simpler method or algorithm to find the repeat unit of array?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a bug in `if(a[j]!=a[j+r*n])`

Why do you add it by `n`? Shouldn't it be: `if(a[j]!=a[j+r*i])`?

Also, the algorithm is a little slow, another way you can solve it is to treat each number as different character in a string, and use Knuth Morris-Pratt (KMP) algo. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

<del>*Will add more info to the answer soon.*</del>

UPDATE:

*Disclaimer: syntax and variable may not be complete*

KMP Implementation:

```
int F[MAX_N];
int main(void){
    int P[MAX_N], T[MAX_N];
    //1. get input, put it into P array, not coded.
    //....
    //2. insert content of P array to T twice.
    int ptr = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<2;i++)
        for(int j = 0;j<length_of_p;j++){
            T[ptr++] = P[j];
        }
    //3. get length of repeated unit.
    int repeated = kmp(P, T, 1);
    //4. print the numbers of repeated unit. i.e. done
    cout<<"REPEATED UNIT: ";
    for(int i = 0;i<repeated;i++)
        cout<< P[i] << " ";
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
void kmp_init(int P[]) {
    F[0] = 0;  F[1] = 0;  
    int i = 1, j = 0;
    while(i<P.size()) {
        if (P[i] == P[j])
            F[++i] = ++j;
        else if (j == 0)
            F[++i] = 0;
        else
            j = F[j];
    }
}

int kmp(int P[], int T[], int start) {
    kmp_init(P);
    int i = start, j = 0;
    int n = T.size(), m = P.size();

    while(i-j <= n-m) {
        while(j < m) {
            if (P[j] == T[i]) {
                i++; j++;
            } else break;
        }
        if (j == m) return i-m;
        else if (j == 0) i++;
        j = F[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug here is in the fact that you check first the case when i is 1, and of course that's going to be detected as your repeat unit.
That's because the line

```
for(int r=1;r<i;r++)
```

will break immediately if `i=1` (your first case).

If you are sure that your numbers will be between 0 and 9 (i.e., only single digit) and you want a "simple" solution (as you say in the title), you can just build a string using the numbers, split the string in substrings and check if they're all equal to each other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int nums[]={1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2};
    char initial_string[255];
    char string_list[255][255];
    int i, j, k, l;
    int found = 0;

    memset(initial_string, 0, 255);
    for(i=0; i < sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int); i++) {
        initial_string[i] = '0' + nums[i];
    }

    int n = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int);
    memset(string_list, 0, 255*255);

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            int count = (int)n/i;
            for (k = 0, j = 0; k < n; k+=i, j++) {
                strncpy(string_list[j], &initial_string[k], i);
            }
            found = 1;
            for (k = 0; k < count; k++) {
                if (strcmp(string_list[0], string_list[k])) {
                    // Different strings!
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Repeat unit: %d\n", i);
}
```

Please note that this code is **NOT** optimal, there are several things to improve, take it as a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use STL set function here. Like that,

```
int main()
{
set< int > s;
  s.insert(1);
  s.insert(3);
  s.insert(2);
  s.insert(1);
  s.insert(3);
  s.insert(2);
  s.insert(1);
  s.insert(3);
  s.insert(2);

   set< int > :: iterator it;
   for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) {
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

It will print distinct elements thus you will find the repeat unit of any array.
Happy Coding !